# unable to locate package problem on ubuntu 16

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am struggling to solve this problem I am having and I would appreciate it if someone could help. During the read me installation file when it says to input 'sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full' it comes up with Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full. I have received support with this problem and have failed to find a solution. this is restricting me from continuing. Do you know why this may be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381558/unable-to-locate-package-problem-on-ubuntu-16/) by [jaaz.gd](https://answers.ros.org/users/76644/jaaz.gd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-01**:
Have you followed the setup instructions to configure APT to use the ros package directory?

```
APT-Sources: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

**Comment by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) on 2021-07-01**:
Sequentially follow the steps given here- [Installation](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)

**Comment by [jaaz.gd](https://answers.ros.org/users/76644/jaaz.gd/) on 2021-07-01**:
i have followed all steps and still get the error, as well as using the above 'APT-Sources: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages' and i now get 'command not found.

**Comment by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) on 2021-07-01**:
Do not skip a single step from the installation guide. Did you run `sudo apt-get update`?

**Comment by [jaaz.gd](https://answers.ros.org/users/76644/jaaz.gd/) on 2021-07-01**:
Yes I have. I have not skipped any steps. I also ask for help at my uni and the tech supervisor that helped also got the same error.

**Comment by [jaaz.gd](https://answers.ros.org/users/76644/jaaz.gd/) on 2021-07-01**:
They think it might be an error with the version as it says Ubuntu 16.04 however that version is end of life so we are using Ubuntu 20

**Comment by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) on 2021-07-01**:
Your question title is misleading. Kinetic packages are not available for Ubuntu 20.04. Either install it on Ubuntu 16 via a virtualbox or install ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04. Quoting their releases page-

> Every ROS release will be supported on exactly one Ubuntu LTS.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-01**:
@trunc8 You should make your comment the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> unable to locate package problem on ubuntu 16

Your question title is misleading. You should always make your system's OS very clear in the question. In this case, your system OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Kinetic packages are not available for Ubuntu 20.04. You can either use Kinetic on Ubuntu 16 via a virtualbox or install ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.

Quoting their [releases page](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions#Release_Schedule)-

> Every ROS release will be supported on exactly one Ubuntu LTS.

---

Originally posted by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) with karma: 156 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1